# How to make a bootable backup of my 14.04 computer

Tags: usb, backup, clone, cd-image, clonezilla

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running the GNOME shell and i want to know how to make a full backup of my os and files and settings. I cannot use remastersys and i have tried clonezilla but keep getting errors. If someone can give me a program, or tutorial on how to do this on 14.04 i would be gracious.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ubuntu, but I know a few other distros support the use of disk dumps to backup your data/system. See more here: http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Dd

I believe for your purposes you would be cloning the disk entirely to your backup hard disk

Let me know if it works :)

EDIT: I just found the relevant Ubuntu documentation, here's a [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging).

Comment: i was looking for something like remastersys, i tried black labv imager but it keeps failing to install from the repo